# cosine distances very large in sklearn NearestNeighbors search

Tags: python, trigonometry

I'm running a KNN nearest neighbor search in a sparse matrix format.

```
nlf = neighbors.NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20,algorithm='brute', metric='cosine')

df_csr 

Out[]: <100x2253274 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 8105964 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

trainY = xrange(100)
nlf.fit(df_csr, trainY)

sf_csr

Out[]: <1x2253274 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 7172 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

result1 = nlf.kneighbors(sf_csr)

result1[1]+1, result1[0]

Out[230]:
(array([[ 63,  10,  78,  19,  40,  14,  23,  53,  11,  66,  29,  77,  69,
      83,  76,  25, 100,  22,  15,  21]], dtype=int64),
 array([[ 0.98304724,  0.9903958 ,  0.99536581,  0.99604388,  0.99706035,
      0.99749375,  0.99768032,  0.99778807,  0.99779205,  0.99783219,
      0.99822192,  0.9982969 ,  0.99831123,  0.99840337,  0.99849419,
      0.99858861,  0.99861923,  0.99863749,  0.99865913,  0.99875224]]))
```

The cosine distances are very large > 0.983

Infact, I ran this for 20 odd segments and most of them have cosine distances large > 0.983

Are the results alright? Did I miss something? Is the cosine distance ( and cosine similarity) calculated correctly by sklearn?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not mistaking cosine similarity with a distance measure? The cosine similarity of identical vectors is `1`, not `0`. On a more procedural note, it might help you get answers if you added tags for the libraries you're using (especially whichever one is providing the `NearestNeighbors` function).

Comment: I realized that the cosine distances are correct. They were high because there was very little commonality between the sampled data.